# Quickly Changing/Picking/Selecting Cell Font In Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office, fonts

When I have a cell selected, or font within a cell highlighted and I want to change the font, I go up to Font dropdown list and scroll through to find my new font. this is slow and error-prone. Naturally, I would think I could begin to type the name of the font within the box to filter the fonts down to a manageable list. This doesn't work. Only the first letter.

For example, when picking "courier" font, I press "c" and I am immediately given "Cambria". When I try to type "co" it seems to give me "oOCR...." This is quite annoying.

Is there a better way to change fonts in excel? Typing on that font drop down is counter-productive at this point.

Comment: Hm, I can't replicate your issue. What version of Excel are you in? When I try, I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AMZxr.gif).  If you know what font you want, you could set a macro I suppose...

Comment: It works like @BruceWayne describes in 2010 and up. You tagged with 2010. Is that your version? If so, disable any add-ins or start Excel in safe mode to see if it works natively.

Comment: @BruceWayne that's how it should work and it's not. Btw, what did you use to make that gif?

Comment: @teylyn I will try without addins and disable any worksheet events from VBA and report back. Thanks.

Comment: @teylyn, restarting excel seemed to fix it. Maybe during my vba development something got twisted. It's now working correctly with my addin enabled. thanks!